# CSS Selector: Children of class with one of the following classes

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a requirement for a CSS selector where all children of a given class which contain one of n classes are affected.

My container is `.k-editor` and the children I am looking to affect are all the bootstrap columns `col-xs-1, col-xs-2` etc.

So I tried this

```
.k-editor 
.col-xs-1, .col-sm-1, .col-md-1, .col-lg-1,
.col-xs-2, .col-sm-2, .col-md-2, .col-lg-2,
.col-xs-3, .col-sm-3, .col-md-3, .col-lg-3,
.col-xs-4, .col-sm-4, .col-md-4, .col-lg-4,
.col-xs-5, .col-sm-5, .col-md-5, .col-lg-5,
.col-xs-6, .col-sm-6, .col-md-6, .col-lg-6,
.col-xs-7, .col-sm-7, .col-md-7, .col-lg-7,
.col-xs-8, .col-sm-8, .col-md-8, .col-lg-8,
.col-xs-9, .col-sm-9, .col-md-9, .col-lg-9,
.col-xs-10, .col-sm-10, .col-md-10, .col-lg-10,
.col-xs-11, .col-sm-11, .col-md-11, .col-lg-11,
.col-xs-12, .col-sm-12, .col-md-12, .col-lg-12 {
    padding: 0;
}
```

but this seems to ignore the .k-editor parent and apply itself to all columns.

Anyone able to provide some input on what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This code can be shortened:

```
.keditor [class^="col"] {
     padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: Oh thats awesome, I always wondered if a selector like this existed but could never seem to find it. Thanks so much..

Answer (score 3):

This is the shortest solution: `.k-editor [class^="col"]` will match all the children of `.k-editor` whose class starts with `col`.

The other way is to prefix `.k-editor` to each of your comma-separated selectors:

`.k-editor .col-xs-1, .k-editor .col-sm-1, .k-editor .col-md-1, .k-editor .col-lg-1` etc